# Limitations on transforming a vector into another vector with norm-preserving linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an N-dimensional vector, $\vec v_0 = (0,1,0,0,....)^T$. 
I would like to multiply this vector by a product of $n$ $N\times N$ matrices, so that:
$\vec v_f =U_BB_nU_B^{-1}U_FF_nU_F^{-1}\cdot ...\cdot F_2U_F^{-1}U_BB_1U_B^{-1}U_AA_1U_A^{-1}\vec v_0$,
where $B_n$ and $A_n$ are diagonal matrices such that $U_BB_nU_B^{-1}$ is the matrix exponential of a diagonalizable matrix $-i\mathcal{B}$, i.e. $U_B$ is the eigenvectors of $\mathcal{B}$, and $B_n$ is $\sim e^{-i*B_i}$ where $B_i$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{B}$. For each $A_i,B_i$ I have the freedom to rescale all the eigenvalues by some factor, i.e. the matrix $-i\mathcal{B}$ for each of these is changed to $-i\mathcal{B}r_i$ where $r_i$ is some real number. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors are all real.

Here is my question: given a $\vec v_0$ that I know to start with, and a target $\vec v_f$ that I want to reach, are there any clear limitations on 
a) If I can ever exactly reach my target final state?
b) If $n$ must be a certain value to reach this optimal target state?

Another possible clue: $\vec v_f$ is a real vector, but the transformation of $\vec v_0$ in general takes it to a complex vector - so the "best" final vector relative to the target vector would have small imaginary parts, perhaps, or at least relative to the biggest real elements.

Another possible clue: If my target vector is called $\vec v_t$, then I basically would like to maximize $|\vec v_t\cdot\vec v_f|^2$, which ranges from zero to one. From this perspective this is just a well-defined non-linear (since the free parameters enter the matrices in exponentials) optimization problem. I think my main question here is: is there a guaranteed solution just based on linear algebra principles? If I just do a random search through all possible input parameters, how can I know if I am close to a solution?

In 3 Dimensions, I am basically needing to figure out the rotation matrix between two vectors. For higher dimensions, this is a lot more complicated, but maybe the same idea applies a bit. 
Thanks in advance.